# Rails nested model not saving correctly

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, simple-form

Using Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 3.2.13, SimpleForm and ActiveRecord. I have a form for a Contact with an optional Volunteer (a contact can optionally "be" a volunteer, the relationship is one-to-one).

Editing of a contact is currently working fine, the volunteer fields are displayed and saved correctly.

However, when creating a new contact, I get an error message: `Volunteer contact This field is required.`

I'm creating the new contact (and its volunteer) like this: `@model = Contact.new(model)`

And contact allows the setting of the volunteer attributes:

```
class Contact < BaseModel
    has_one :volunteer
    attr_accessible :volunteer_attributes
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :volunteer
end
```

So it seems the Volunteer's contact is not pointing back to the new contact that is created? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Try something like `@contact = Contact.new; @volunteer = @contact.build_volunteer`

Comment: So I simplified my example. In reality this is in a base controller that handles index/view/edit/delete for multiple models. So the real code is `@model = @@source.new(params[:model])` where `@@source` is `Contact` in this case. It works great so far until I started doing nested models. But I think I can make this work w/your suggestions - will try! Thanks.